# Where do I make a circular charts like Chartbeat.com in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am planning on making an analytics dashboard and would like to implement circular charts like the image attached to this question:[image]

and I would like to do it using jQuery. Do you guys have any usefull links to resources or to other SO questions? Would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also take a look at :

http://bernii.github.com/gauge.js/

http://www.justgage.com/

Both of them look really good and seems pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to create an SVG that mimics the appearance you want, and then use JavaScript/jQuery to modify the source of the SVG. The design you're requesting could probably be acheived by simply placing two arcs on top of one another.

Deriving from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3262746/133802) on calculating arcs, creating two overlapping ones could look [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Us6Lw/), which also demonstrates updating the arc dynamically.

Comment: Hey David! Thanks for the answer. After finding out that these type of charts are actually called "Donuts" it was easier to find some nice resources.

Interesting sources: http://mtibben.github.com/jquery.donutchart/example.html

http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-complete/charts-pie-chart/

Answer (score 0):

lethargicpanda's suggestions are cool. Check out [jQuery Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) too. It also allows user input.